# Problems deploying mvc app to sub directory of site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, web-deployment, subdirectory, web-deployment-project

When i place all my files in the root of my site, it overrides the existing site and automatically goes to the calendar application instead of the index.php that i have.

I have an existing site that i cannot change, so i was wondering how i can deploy this in a subdirectory, ex mysite.com\mvc_app\Home\Index

Here is my routing for the route config, any help would be appreciated! (i tried ignoring the blank route but it seems to open the app still, even tho hostbuddy is set to route mysite.com to the index.php as the default page)

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: read about virtual directories in IIS

Comment: Figured it out by adding a subdomain and mapped it to the app :) thanks tho!